# check for todays date plus a set amount of days time in an SQL query and codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to check a database to retrieve some information that has a datetime attached to it.

I want to retrieve some values based on them falling between todays date and 14 days time.

I am using the following as a where clause for retrieving values

set the variable to hold todays date

```
$delivery_date_time = date('Y-m-d');
```

WHERE clause on my SQL statement

```
$this->db->where('delivery_date_time >=', $delivery_date_time);
```

This works and gets me the values for delivery dates on and after today's date.

However I am trying to limit these values to ones that fall between today's date and 10 days in the future.

Comment: Searched everywhere? I just don't believe you

Comment: I am looking for something specific that works in Codeigniter which I am new to using. The code I have works for getting values for and after todays date but when I search for something for setting a limit on my WHERE clause I am not finding anything that works. Maybe my search terms are not suitable. I am still searching by the way but thought someone would have a simple solution to it - sorry once again if my post has offended you

Answer (score 0):

[DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) is what you are looking for. also you can get today's date with CURDATE() function in mysql:

```
WHERE delivery_date_time BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: I am thinking I can add something like this below the first statement to limit the time on the query `$this->db->where('delivery_date_time <=', $fixture_date_time.'+ 10');`

Comment: why? is there such syntax, or did you just made that up rather than using my answer?

Comment: Only because I am using Codeigniter and not sure how to incorporate your answer into that

Comment: Volkan thank you for your help. Your answer may work but it wasn't what I thought I needed for using with Codeigniter, sorry about that. I found a similar thread to mine after some more digging and after following a few links I ended up here -stackoverflow.com/questions/16524906/… - where I found a solution that worked. I created a similar variable and added it to my code. $ten_days_ahead = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+10 days"));  and then in my WHERE clause  $this->db->where('delivery_date_time <=', $ten_days_ahead);

Comment: you're doing essentially the same, just with php instead of mysql.